# Site name Computer Vs Building materials

Tags: discussion

I may be completely missing something on my mobile view but should there be a mention of PC in the site title? 
Or could have new people asking about hammers and nails.

Again apologies if I'm missing it on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ongoing discussion, see [What type of hardware is allowed?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-type-of-hardware-is-allowed).

In this site's definition, it was sort of taken for granted that the site would be about computer or related hardware, rather than the typical DIY stuff you find in a hardware store. The reality of having the site has shown that actually, there's going to be some confusion about what's allowed.

If we decide that it *is* only PC and related hardware we talk about here, then that might eventually result in a name change to include something. However, our help center's "on-topic" page should also define what's allowed here and what isn't - so it also might not.

Still in definition.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info

Answer (score 2):

It is my strong opinion that this site needs to clarify the scope of the site before really answering the "name?" question.

As you see, "Hardware" means a lot of different things than "Computer hardware." While the initial idea behind the site might have been clearly defined as one thing, the implicit site scope is much more broad.

There are still a lot of scope related questions which need to be figured out before this can really be answered.