# Are small electronics on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to discuss the closure of [Baby monitor that can have multiple transmitting stations on the same channel](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/179/baby-monitor-that-can-have-multiple-transmitting-stations-on-the-same-channel)

The close reason provided:

> "This question does not appear to be about hardware recommendations, within the scope defined in the help center."

Are small electronics on topic? According to one of the answers [here](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/81/57), it is. Admittedly, this is my own answer, but it does currently hold the highest score.

> - Small gadgets (for example the baby monitor question I asked, or the internet controlled power outlet )

Should we have a scope that covers electronic gadgets?

Comment: Aya, the biggest issue that we're facing is now the definition of "hardware". Right now, I would consider it off-topic, but it doesn't look like we've ever defined what "hardware" is, and it can really be anything.

Comment: That's the point of this question. Do we extend "hardware" to small gadgets? I'm ok with the question remaining closed if we do not, but the idea here is to figure out where boundaries of "hardware" are for the site.

Comment: I completely agree. Without a definition of hardware, we're literally just kicking ourselves for the long run.

Answer (score 4):

The root of this problem (and a number of other "is this on topic" questions we've had) is that we don't have a definition of what "hardware" is to us. To that end, I'm going to propose one. I say we should accept questions about:

- Computers and peripherals (mice, printers, USB drives, keyboards, anything you connect to a computer to use)
- Computer-related hardware (such as components like memory or CPUs)
- Electronic devices (phones, drones, baby monitors)

---

That's a combination of a number of answers from the linked thread. Once we get into public beta and have moderators, it may be a good idea to start a meta thread to finally define scope. The mods can then edit the help pages to reflect it.

So, on this particular situation: baby monitors are *on-topic*.

Comment: Part of defining "hardware", for the purposes of this site, is determining what is and isn't on topic. I find it easier to have such discussions when an actual question has already been posted. It allows discussion of exactly why such a question does or doesn't fit. Defining "hardware" is important, but I think questions that push the edges of that definition are also important in defining "hardware". To that end, though, I agree with your definition and determination that the question is on topic.

Comment: @Andy No arguments there. Questions that stretch the scope are important, but I also think we need a base position to work from - if we go into public beta without it, it could easily turn to being a close-fest, with people closing as they see fit rather than to any specific guideline.

Comment: @ArtOfCode It's rather the opposite: when we go into public beta, there won't be many people who can vote to close, whereas in the private beta, everybody can.

Comment: @Gilles Aye. I didn't quite mean a close-fest, but I couldn't think up a better word. I meant more like everyone who *can* close vote doing so in an unordered fashion, adhering only to their own guidelines.