# Moderator closing questions when he is unsure if they are on topic

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderators, closed-questions

I have [asked this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/where-civilian-can-get-most-powerful-laser) today and moderator closed [it because](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/where-civilian-can-get-most-powerful-laser#comment-2499)

> I'm closing this question because we don't tend to deal with
> recommendations of manufacturers or stores, only hardware. You can
> rephrase the question to ask for the hardware itself, and we may be
> able to reopen it, though in not sure if losers are on topic.

**If moderator is unsure if type of hardware (like 'losers') is on topic shouldn't he first make sure if they are or not and then go around closing questions?**

[from tour:](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)

> Ask about...
>
> specific hardware that would enable you to perform a certain task

Most powerful laser to fry stuff.

> Don't ask about...
>
> Technical support of any kind
> Step-by-step instructions for "do-it-yourself" installation
> Anything not directly related to recommending hardware
> Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an
> extremely long answer

Answer (score 6):

Really? You're calling this on a typo?

1. "Lasers", not "losers".
2. Please take a look at [What is Hardware?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware). It details what's in scope. Lasers are neither a primary computing platform nor directly designed to interface with one, therefore are off topic.

The tour can't cover everything, and the "ask about" points certainly don't. We haven't had any questions about recommending stores or markets yet, so we hadn't thought to put them in "don't ask about".

Since you're also complaining about your comments being deleted, I'll explain that too. I deleted a few comments on your question on main because

- they were getting chatty, which is not what comments are for
- and in one of them, you had a go at trying to reveal my real name, which is **Not On**.

I also deleted precisely one of your comments here on Meta, because you weren't Being Nice. If they weren't being used as examples to support another meta post, I would delete a few more here for the same reason.

Comment: I am calling this on temp moderator abusing his powers. Point me where lasers are not allowed, please.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius It's linked in this very post, and explained.

Comment: Don't you feel like you are making decisions for everyone here, must feel good.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius I'm enforcing the scope that we as a community decided on.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius, you are off base. ArtOfCode has explained his reasoning. You may disagree, but calling moderator abuse because of this is inappropriate. His reasoning is sound. He links to the guidelines this community has agreed upon. If you disagree with that, start a relevant meta post or post your argument in the linked post.

Answer (score 4):

As a fellow moderator, I fully support ArtOfCode's decision here. If I'd been awake at the time, I would have closed it for the same reason - if I'm not sure that something is off topic in one aspect, but I *know* it is in another aspect, it's off topic.

Comment: As a fellow moderator, how do you justify him deleting all my comments, but leaving his? BTW I don't deny (now) that question is off-topic, it certainly is, still ArtOfCode `could have posted link to meta post and said sorry this is 'computer hardware only'` which I would be perfectly fine with.

Comment: Instead he posted this. `I'm closing this question because we don't tend to deal with recommendations of manufacturers or stores, only hardware. You can rephrase the question to ask for the hardware itself, and we may be able to reopen it, though in not sure if lasers are on topic.` IMHO - moderators should't troll newcomers

Comment: That's... not trolling, @MatasVaitkevicius. That's trying to get information across, while conveying that the root question might not be on topic here.

Comment: `and we may be able to reopen it` - how can you reopen question about lasers if forum is about computer hardware?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius actually, `and we may be able to reopen it - though I'm not sure if lasers are on-topic`. Without that certainty, there *was* a likelihood that we could have reopened it.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius I deleted a number of your comments for a variety of reasons, including being Not Nice and attempting to reveal my personal information.

Comment: The comments ArtOfCode deleted were 100% out of line. Don't do that again.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius More to the point, *all* your comments is a massive exaggeration. I've deleted a grand total of 4 of your comments, across main and meta.