# Change name to Computer Hardware Recommendations

Tags: discussion, scope

Current name `Hardware Recommendations` [is deceptive](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/moderator-closing-questions-when-he-is-unsure-if-they-are-on-topic) I recommend to change name to `Computer Hardware Recommendations`.

Comment: You'll need better arguments than that if you want to persuade the team to do this. I speak from experience on Open Source.

Answer (score 5):

**No.**

Your argument for a name change is not convincing. It is based on a single, personal, misunderstanding of the scope of this site. I'm also hesitant to discuss a name change when the response to your misunderstanding was to immediately [declare moderator abuse](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/moderator-closing-questions-when-he-is-unsure-if-they-are-on-topic#comment637_374), instead of asking a question about the scope or posting a counter argument about the scope. The appropriate thing to do when you disagree with something that had been decided before you joined the community is to ask for clarification or make your arguments to change something, not say someone is abusing the power they've been given.

Additionally, we [support](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/266/57) recommendations for more than computer hardware. There is, however, the requirement that the hardware must be able to interface with a computer.

---

Changing a site name is a [one time thing](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1053/9092). It is very time consuming. [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/should-we-change-our-name-redux) took [five months](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/changing-the-name-of-moderators-se-the-saga-continues/197#197) to do. It involves moderator time, community manager time and community member time. New names have to be voted up on, debated and most of all they need to better describe the community than the current name.