# Requests for hardware for prank/ possible malicious use?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1286/usb-rubber-ducky-alternative) got bumped to the front page.

From the way it is worded, it is clear that the OP is looking for hardware that can be used for a prank device, but claims not to be looking to use it for malicious purposes.

Is this type of hardware request on topic?  I mean yes, it connects/communicates with a computer, but the goal of the device is to prank/"mess with" people who have low computer skills, which is akin to harassment.

(also, I am surprised there is not an ethics tag for meta posts)

Comment: Do you consider it your, or that of Stack Exchange's moral responsibility to defend those who are illiterate in the usage of computers from moderately malicious intent.

I would think not, which means it is on topic.

Comment: @RubyJunk  Actually, I feel that it is ethically my responsibility to protect those people from any level of malicious intent.   And now, from you posting this comment here, it is clearly evident that you requested the information so as to engage in acts of "moderately malicious intent."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these are on topic.

It is **not** our job to determine malicious intent. If the question meets the criteria we've [set out](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/266/57), then it is on topic. A "prank" device can meet all of our requirements (electronic and primarily a computing platform).

Comment: Ah, so I take it SE's legal team has covered the whole problem of what happens when someone finds out who gave someone information on how to do something which causes harm then?   That was why I was asking.

Comment: There are federal laws that remove SE's liability for user generated content. Someone reading a user's post about prank hardware, isn't going to get them in trouble.

Comment: So, if a person is to clearly state that the requested hardware is for malicious intent, what then?

Comment: Then it's really up to you on whether or not you want to answer, edit out the part about it being malicious, or simply ignore it.