# On topic: dash cams?

Tags: discussion

I have spent many hours searching, but can't find a dual camera front & rear dashcam system - where both cameras are inside the vehicle.

There are hundreds where you mount the rear camera outside the vehicle, to help with parking. I don't want that. I woudl really prefer a syste where both cameras are mounted on the rear-view mirror.

Would it be on or off-topic to ask for a recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

On or off topic? - [It's off topic](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware), to be "hardware", according to this site's definition, it needs to be connected to a computer at least most of the time to operate.

On almost all SE sites you can visit the (❔) in the upper right corner, choose "Help Center", and view the FAQ titled: "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)" - occasionally that hasn't been edited and contains a generic template, in that case there's often a Meta discussion that reveals such info.

A search for "[dual camera front & rear dashcam system mirror](https://www.google.com/search?ei=PwalW6_oFeLr9AP1jKCYDQ&q=dual%20camera%20front%20%26%20rear%20dashcam%20system%20mirror)" turns up plenty of results: "[Falcon Zero F360 HD DVR Dual Dash Cam](https://www.falconzero.com/products/falcon-zero-f-360-hd-rear-view-mirror-car-dual-dash-camera-car-dvr?variant=14561335239)", "[DuoView - 2.7 Inch Car Rear View Mirror with Dual Dash Cameras](http://www.plusbuyer.com/duoview-27-inch-car-rear-view-mirror-with-dual-dash-cameras-p-5935.html)", etc.