# Are questions about robot vacuum cleaners on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, specific-question

I tend to read all questions on Hardware Recs (since I had 500 rep or something like that), and I stumbled upon the question: [Robot Vacuum for Stairs?](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16200/robot-vacuum-for-stairs)

I don't really know the perfect definition of "hardware" on this site (although I have read and closed a lot of questions), so would this be on-topic according to the [What is Hardware?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware) FAQ here?

Comment: "If someone asked for a shredder that communicates how many pages it's eaten to a computer to comply with some security standard, I'd say it's on topic. I would also say that a standard home shredder like I have, which just runs the blades when I stuff something in it, would be off topic" -- It seems like this question would be off-topic if you agree with the shredder being off-topic. If the user was asking about a robot vacuum that could be controlled by Home Assistant and had all of these "interface" requirements then I think that would have brought the question into on-topic.

Comment: Yea okay thats the shredder again, but it's indeed pretty close...