# Recommendations for digital camera with very specific features on topic?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a digital camera with very specific features.  It would be hooked up to a computer on a regular basis to view/download images/videos.

Would this be on topic here?

I've read [What is Hardware?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware) and [What type of hardware is allowed?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-type-of-hardware-is-allowed), but I'm not sure what decisions have been made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say yes.

A digital camera performs more than one meaningful task on its own, and is operated by a user. I therefore see it as a PCP as defined in the "What is Hardware?" post.

Even better, given you've got "very specific requirements" - as always, the more specific you can be, the better.

Comment: I agree.  I think that, ideally, we would have a stable of experts who are active in places like [photography.SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) and other such sites answering those kinds of questions.  Over there, not everyone loves those questions, but over here, it is our raison d'etre.

Comment: Wow... I guess people don't read meta.  I already received 2 downvotes (out of 6 views) on http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1402/portable-digital-camera-with-high-quality-sensor-and-optics