# Are questions regarding PLC's, associated motors and other peripherals on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

As given in [this question](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-type-of-hardware-is-allowed) and the most up-voted answer, it's suggested that PLC-related questions *may* be on-topic. However, upon reading the [tour](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour), it points out [this meta question](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware), which indicates that *only* consumer-computer related systems are on-topic.

I have a question *specifically* regarding a motor to perform a specific function, that *must* be able to be driven from a PLC (even if it's as simple as a "move forward" or "move backward" signal), but I'm very seriously confused as to whether it fits here or not.

So, is a question regarding a PLC **peripheral** on-topic? Not a PLC itself, but a device that would be controlled through the PLC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [latter meta question](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware) that you referred to is our current canonical definition of scope. Undo's answer provides a very nicely quotable definition:

> Hardware is any **primarily electronic item** that can perform more than one task, designed to interface with, connect to, or be, **a primary computing platform** in day-to-day operation.
>
> A **primary computing platform** is any primarily electronic item that can **perform meaningful tasks** on its own with minimal external support, and designed to be **operated by a user**, consumer or professional.

Now, a PLC peripheral is *not* a PCP, but the PLC itself *is*, I'd say - it performs meaningful tasks with limited external support, and is operated by a professional (i.e. you, the developer). Since peripherals for that PLC by definition interface with it, that makes them on-topic under "interfaces with a PCP".

So - **yes, that's on-topic**. Usual rules and guidance about [providing enough detail](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/8) applies.

Comment: Excellent - I'll be sure to read the "providing enough detail" link when I have more time, but I'll refrain from posting the question until then as well. :)

Comment: @202_accepted Awesome. TL;DR: we need enough information to be able to filter potential solutions down to a handful of products rather than "literally any monitor/keyboard/PC/motor will fit"; the more information you can provide, the better.

Comment: Absolutely, I just scanned that and it's all pretty basic, *entirely expected* common-sense information it seems. (Things that I would completely expect to be required, that is.) Much appreciated on the response, this completely clears up what my concerns were.